# Angularjs Doesnt work after Deployment

Tags: c#, angularjs

Angularjs Part is not working after Deploying in IIS 8.5  , this is my js file
this code works in local machine with Visual Studio 2012

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller("DataViewController", ["$scope", "RequestService", function($scope, RequestService) {
    $scope.Requests = [];

    RequestService.GetRequests().then(function (d) {
        $scope.Requests = d.data
    });
}])

.factory('RequestService', function ($http) { 
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetRequests = function () {
        return $http.get('/Data/EmployeeRequests');
    }
    return fac;
});
```

Comment: what does it shows in console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server http://localhost/Data/EmployeeRequests responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: angular.js:9734 GET http://localhost/Data/EmployeeRequests 404 (Not Found)

Comment: i tried your answer but it gives same Result ....

Comment: can i get a teamviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your application cannot find the resource

Just change

**From:**

```
.factory('RequestService', function ($http) { 
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetRequests = function () {
        return $http.get('/Data/EmployeeRequests');
    }
    return fac;
});
```

**To:**

```
.factory('RequestService', function ($http) { 
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetRequests = function () {
        return $http.get('Data/EmployeeRequests');
    }
    return fac;
});
```

Comment: This Works with me just need to set the Path as  return $http.get('../Data/EmployeeRequests');

Answer (score 0):

You are missing explicit type annotations on your factory declaration.

There may be a problem with minification of .js files. On your local machine VS prevents bundle optimization, when you deploy your solution to IIS on prod server - ASP.NET minimizes and bundles all your js and css files. Thus turning

```
function($http) { ... }
```

into

```
function(a) { ... }
```

To solve problem use explicit annotations:

```
.controller(['dep1', 'dep2', '$http', function(dep1, dep2, $http) {... }]);
```

or

```
Controller.$inject = ['dep1', 'dep2', '$http'];
```